# Reflection class to get all properties of any object not returning all properties

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have  to find out all the properties within the object for that I am using method e.GetType().GetProperties()

e is dynamic type inheriting from IEvent . 
e has multiple propertie s

Issue which I am facing is propertyInfos collection does not contain ABC.Domain.Contract.Base.DInfo from RSummary and only it has ABC.Comon.Contract.Base.DInfo from REventBase Class

I need both the classes should come in propertyInfos collection.

Is there any specific property which I have to provide which will bring all DInfo irresppective of there namespaces

```
private static void ProcessEvents()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var e in allEvents)
        {
            try
            {

                PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;

                //MemberInfo[] info = type.FindMembers(MemberTypes.All, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, new MemberFilter(searchFilter), "tt");
                //MemberInfo[] info = type.FindMembers(MemberTypes.All, BindingFlags.Default, new MemberFilter(searchFilter), "Submitted");
                propertyInfos = e.GetType().GetProperties(
                    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic // Get public and non-public
                    | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance // Get instance + static
                    | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.ExactBinding);
                foreach (var property in propertyInfos)
                {
                    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(ABC.Domain.Contract.Base.DInfo))
                    {
                        //Do something 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Do something  Do Something Else
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ea)
            {
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ea)
    {
    }
}


public class FSubmitted : REventBase
{
    public RSummary NewForm { get; set; }
}

public abstract class REventBase : Event
{
    public Guid RId { get; set; }
    public ABC.Comon.Contract.Base.DInfo RDInfo { get; set; }
}

public class RSummary
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    //public FormType Type { get; set; }
    public FRef FRef { get; set; }
    public ABC.Domain.Contract.Base.DInfo Submitted { get; set; }
    public ABC.Domain.Contract.Base.DInfo Saved { get; set; }
    public ABC.Domain.Contract.Base.DInfo Signed { get; set; }
    public bool IsSigned { get; set; }
}



public class DInfo
{
    public bool someThing { get; set; }
}


public class DInfo
{
    public bool someThing { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This works just fine for me.  I get the PropertyInfo array as expected.  Are you certain you're passing in the right type?

Comment: Yes I am passing right type , and I am always getting type ABC.Comon.Contract.Base.DInfo , I should get both in Array i.e ABC.Comon.Contract.Base.DInfo and ABC.Domain.Contract.Base.DInfo

Comment: I think you are referring to the situation where only properties declared by the type itself are found, not properties inherited from the base class?

Comment: Ohh , I want properties which are being inherited from base type also

Comment: Since you omitted `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`, I think you should get inherited (accessible) non-static properties already, so I might not understand what you ask, after all. Can you extend your code above to a full program we can run ourselves to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Side note: do not use empty catch blocks.  They swallow _any_ exception that occurs.  If you have _specific_ exceptions you want to ignore either use a more specific exception type, or better yet, _anticipate_ what would cause the exception and handle it.

Comment: Here do we have any property which will get all child/derived properties of existing Type